# Can't change a single value in a dataframe if that value is 'True' or 'False'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For some reason I can't change a single value in a dataframe if that value is 'True' or 'False'.  Other values can be changed without issue.  I've tried df.at,  df.ix,  df.iat, and df.replace with no luck.

My dataframe is 'df'.  The 0,4 element is 500 and can be changed to 700:

```
df.iat[0,4]
Out[191]: 500

df.iat[0,4] = 700
df.iat[0,4]
Out[193]: 700

The 0,6 element is 'True' and resists any change:
df.iat[0,6]
Out[194]: True

df.iat[0,6] = 700
df.iat[0,6]
Out[196]: True
```

There are no errors, warnings, nothing, it just refuses to change the df.

What is the correct way to change specific True/False entries in a dataframe?

Comment: To be honest, I really don't see `iat` being used much, I wonder if this is a bug (or, just carry-over unusual behaviour)

Comment: I cannot reproduce in the latest version of pandas

Comment: Following on from @Chris, then, what version of pandas is this?

Comment: I think they fixed in 0.23

Comment: interesting... if the shape of my dataframe is `(1,n)` replacing `True` with `df.iat` i cannot replace; however, if the shape is `(>1, n)` i can replace with `df.iat`. I would use `df.loc` seems to work in both situations.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.3 and doing 'import pandas as pd'.

Comment: @Amzie what version of pandas: `pd.__version__`

Comment: Looks like '0.23.4'  -- thanks for all the quick responses, btw

Comment: Tried making this change interactively in Spyder.  Double-clicked on a 'True' element, changed it to '0', and hit enter.  Spyder changed the element to 'False'.  So looks like the datatype of the column is forcing things.  How do I query or change the datatype of a column?